Matching on actual earnings versus matching on the kind of unexpectedness in earnings
For simplicity, lets assume this is a question about linear modeling, although I am actually looking at some non-linear models and am willing to consider other models if they would be more advantageous.
I have a large number of short, overlapping two-year panels. I want to glue these together in order to create a synthetic panel of longer duration, for purposes of studying income dynamics and lifetime, or perhaps decadal, income inequality. To do this I need to attach households or persons in the  second year of one panel to the households or persons in the first year of the following panel. Within panels I have information in the data on which households or persons match (for most years), though people who move into or out of the area may not be assigned a match. I want the matches to be economically similar to the matched in economic behavior and outcomes.
As a preliminary matter, I construct Mincer equations for each sample panel-year that predict income from education and training history and demographical characteristics. There is, however, considerable variation in earnings (well, log earnings) among individuals matched on other characteristics. Moreover, I have established that these errors are highly persistent. So I thought I would toss the ratio of forecast earnings to actual earnings into my matching algorithm, and let least squares sort it out.
But then I thought, why use this ratio as a predictor when I can use the actual earnings in my similarity algorithm used in matching. Although the two approaches seem to choose similar people as matches, almost all the actual pairs produced by matching change.
And since then I have been going around in circles, changing my mind back and forth repeatedly. Finally I thought I should ask people who actually know something about such models. And hence I appeal to y'all.

A few approaches come to mind. Imo, ground truth wrt matching shd be based on the within panel matches. 1) build propensity score matches based on the hholds that match within panels. 2) Gary King (Harvard polisci) prefers Mahalanobis distance matching over propensity scoring. 3) Treat the data as a type of Heckman sample bias problem with the base data as in 1) and adjust the nonmatching data with the resulting distance function. Choose the most error minimizing approach. That said, would be interested in more theoretically driven approaches.
